# Random results in if-statements

Tags: swift, if-statement

I have this code that gives the wrong result.  The combination EE and Aa sometimes gives "black" if I press Aa after selecting EE... Other times it gives the correct result.  Any tips?

This is my code:

```
//genotype
var ext = "ee"
var ago = "aa"
var gre = "gg"

func checkPicture() {
//Base coat regular
    if ext == "EE" || ext == "Ee" && ago == "aa" {
        baseLayer.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "black")
        base = String("black")
    }
    if ago == "Aa" || ago == "AA" && ext == "EE" || ext == "Ee" {
        baseLayer.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bay")
        base = String("bay")
        }
    if ext == "ee" {
        baseLayer.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "chestnut")
        base = String("chestnut")
    }
```

//buttons

```
@IBAction func `extension`(_ sender: UIButton) {
    ext = String(sender.titleLabel!.text ?? "ee")
    genotype.text = checkGenotype()

    eeno.isSelected = false
    eema.isSelected = false
    eeye.isSelected = false
    sender.isSelected = true

    checkPicture()
}
@IBAction func agouti(_ sender: UIButton) {
    ago = String(sender.titleLabel!.text ?? "aa")
    genotype.text = checkGenotype()

    aano.isSelected = false
    aama.isSelected = false
    aaye.isSelected = false
    sender.isSelected = true
}
@IBAction func grey(_ sender: UIButton) {
    gre = String(sender.titleLabel!.text ?? "gg")
    genotype.text = checkGenotype()

    ggno.isSelected = false
    ggma.isSelected = false
    ggye.isSelected = false
    sender.isSelected = true
}
```

Comment: First of all it looks like you should use `else` in your code, `else if ago == "Aa"` and `else if ext == "ee"` and secondly if you get this issue after pressing something (buttons?) in a special order then the issue might not only be with this function but also with how and when it is called.

Comment: What does "gg" have to do with your code?

Comment: GG comes in later, in all there are ten genes that affect the outcome.  I forgot to add the IBActions that trigger them.  Ill put that in now

Answer (score 1):

It's Simple your condition's are bit confusing

```
func checkPicture() {
//Base coat regular
    if (ext == "EE" || ext == "Ee") && ago == "aa" { // added bracket
        baseLayer.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "black")
        base = String("black")
    }
    if (ago == "Aa" || ago == "AA") && (ext == "EE" || ext == "Ee") {
        baseLayer.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bay")
        base = String("bay")
        }
    if ext == "ee" {
        baseLayer.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "chestnut")
        base = String("chestnut")
    }
}
```

This should resolve your problem. you forgot to add bracket at required places.

Comment: I tried this but I still get kind of random results

Comment: @imeyer This is where debugging or print statements would help you trace out the problem.

Comment: Add debug point there and try to debug it for various inputs. you can search for how to debug ios application, this will give you some points